# The spin loading does not disappear in the IOS environment of my flutter application

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, xcode, firebase

I have a problem with my application made in flutter.

When I do the debug, both in the xcode simulator and with an external IOS device, I get a spin loading, as if it was loading something. This only happens to me in IOS.

[image]

When debugging in VSCode I have some messages that say a lot and when debugging in XCode I have other messages, but I still can't identify the problem.

VSCode (with simulator device):

[image]

Xcode (with physical device):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of circustances such as you testing your app on Xcode, if you arethere might be an error with your version of Xcode or flutter, it also might not be packaged correctly. Also the error - `Hit maximum Timestamp count, will start dropping events`  can be addresed by changing what FPS the Animation plays at, making it faster could possibly help. It also seems that a folder named Voiced is not accesible adressing these issues can help fix this problem. If none of these work try debugging with Visual Studio as there is a wide variety of debug tools.